# Nuxt fetch hook: why triggered both in server and in client?

Tags: nuxt.js

> fetch is called on server-side when rendering the route, and on client-side when navigating.

I understand Nuxt.js enables the concept of Universal apps, but why would anyone need to have a fetch hook block executed in both server and client? Sounds redundant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially used for the isomorphic (aka Universal) app aspect. So, if you have `ssr: true`, this will help you for performance and SEO by generating the content ahead of time, hence on the server too.

It is done on both side because you need to have the same content on both Server and Client, otherwise there will be a DOM missmatch and the hydration will fail (implying a huge performance penalty!).

And `target: static` + `ssr: true` is a common combo, especially if hosting on Vercel/Netlify because it will provide performance, SEO and still all the benefits of an SPA.

If you use your Nuxt app as SPA only (`ssr: false`), the benefit is a bit less impressive but people usually come to Nuxt for it's SSR/SSG aspect.
But then, you're stuck waiting on your app while your whole SPA is doing it's thing and...you can say goodbye to SEO.

If you don't like it, you can always set `fetchOnServer` to `false` per component or in `nuxt.config.js`.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch#options

Lastly, when it says that this will be generated on both server and client, we do need to understand that the server is making the call:

- when we are generating the static content, this is not the case anymore after the initial hydration is complete
- **once** if `target: server`, once the JS is shipped to the browser, the SPA will handle the subsequent calls on client side

It's not like it'a huge waste and that the server is always doing the call for you on each client side navigation (MPA approach).

---

As a sidenote (using `asyncData`), when generating some pages from an API, you can use the already computed server payload and not have to fetch it on the client again. Useful for some purely static content like a blog!
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-payload

Comment: "[...] you need to have the same content on both Server and Client, otherwise there will be a DOM missmatch and the hydration will fail (implying a huge performance penalty!)." 

I do not understand: the point of universal apps is having some content rendered server sided, and some client sided while sharing same code base. Splitting rendering means not all content needs  to be present in both server and client. 

Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DanielMartinez some SSG/SSG code can be useful to fix the issues coming from an SPA app. If your app is generated only on client side, you will have poor performance (web metrics) and no SEO mainly. Having it only done on server only will have the downside of typical Wordpress apps with a full reload of your page and a query to a server (server that you need to pay for btw). Static rendering + universal app is pretty much the best usually, because you do have back + front + no server to pay for. For more info on the possible hydration issues: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/vue-hydration-error/

Comment: isnt this triggering your API call twice? just asking

Comment: @PirateApp probably is, double-check on the backend side!