# Nuxt 2 - Do not run fetch while in SSR mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a page where Google will redirect to (oAuth). It is al working perfectly but there is one downside.

Google redirects the user to mysite.com/register?code=foo.

Obviously Nuxt will load the page twice. Once for SSR and once for the cliënt. That means that the account gets created two times.

Is there a way to prevent Nuxt from executing my fetch in SSR mode and only do it in cliënt mode? I tried the process method but it is not working.

```
if (code.value !== '' && process.client && !process.server) {
    fetch(process.env.baseUrl + 'login-with-google', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ "code": code.value })
    })
}
```

So basically all that I want is that my code is NOT ran while in SSR mode, just once when in de cliënt mode i.e. the webpage is loaded for the visitor.

I tried the tips kissu gave me but it keeps ending up with an error.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ddNG.png)

I even copy and pasted the example code, and I still get the same error.
See the code below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Blog posts</h1>
    <template v-if="$fetchState.pending">
      <content-placeholders>
        <content-placeholders-text :lines="20" />
      </content-placeholders>
    </template>
    <template v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
      <p>Error while fetching posts: {{ $fetchState.error.message }}</p>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="post of posts" :key="post.id">
          <n-link :to="`/posts/${post.id}`">
            {{ post.title }}
          </n-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <n-link to="/posts/404">
            404 post
          </n-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  defineComponent,
  useFetch,
  useContext,
  ref,
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const posts = ref(null)

    const { $http } = useContext()

    useFetch(async () => {
      posts.value = await $http
        .$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(posts => posts.slice(0, 20))
    })

    return { posts }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Nuxt will not load the page two times, the client side is a hydration (subtle difference). As for your issue, you may use `fetchOnServer: false` (not sure of the syntax, check the doc) to only call fetch client side.

Comment: As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68520256/8816585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [shown here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch#options), you can use `fetchOnServer: false`.

```html
<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    this.posts = await this.$http.$get('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts')
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am using Nuxt 2 with compositon API so I will have to find out how to get it working there first still but this is awesome!

Comment: @Angelo I'm not sure that the hook is available with Nuxt2 + CAPI, but don't feel obliged to write everything in CAPI either, Options API is totally fine too. Nvm it looks like it's available: https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/examples/useFetch You could try to pass a key down there or maybe check for the project's issues/discussions (if it takes the same options object).

Comment: This is how to achieve that: https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/342#issuecomment-993309567

Comment: Oh wouw that simple! thank you so much! Last question. This does mean that I have to use useFetch right? I will be unable to use the fetch function build-in in Javascript right?

Comment: @Angelo `useFetch` makes you use something really similar to `fetch` so it should not be a huge problem. But you can use pretty much anything with it at the end of the day.

Comment: Error in fetch(): TypeError: Cannot read property '$get' of undefined. That what I keep getting. I have installed the http packages in nuxt. But when I hover that function it does recognize it as a NuxtHttpInstance.

Comment: @Angelo I recommend creating a new question with all the needed details for that one. Especially if the error is related to typescript.